# Location Data Google Photos API

Tags: google-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

When I query a photo in Google photos via the API, it doesn't return any location data that is associated with the image.  I can see the location on the map when I view the information about the image in Google Photos, however the API doesn't give me these coordinates.

```
[mediaMetadata] => Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_MediaMetadata Object
        (
            [creationTime] => 2018-07-13T13:20:38Z
            [height] => 4032
            [photoType:protected] => Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Photo
            [photoDataType:protected] => 
            [videoType:protected] => Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Video
            [videoDataType:protected] => 
            [width] => 3024
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [photo] => Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Photo Object
                (
                    [apertureFNumber] => 1.8
                    [cameraMake] => Apple
                    [cameraModel] => iPhone 8
                    [exposureTime] => 
                    [focalLength] => 3.99
                    [isoEquivalent] => 50
                    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [modelData:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [processed:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 16):

It appears that Google has no intention of sharing photos location via the Photos API.

You can do that with Google Drive API if it suits you, [here is an article](https://www.labnol.org/code/20059-image-exif-and-location/) on how to get EXIF.

For reference, rhe location field used to appear in the `MediaMetadata` fields as "Not yet available", but any reference in the Google Photos API, after release, was removed except for the [docs about downloading an image](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#image-base-urls), where it's stated: "If you want to download the image retaining all the EXIF metadata **except the location metadata**, concatenate the base URL with the d parameter".

There is [a ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80379228) for this, with nearly 500 upvotes, add your own if you're the very hopeful kind of person.

Answer (score 9):

Even though the PHP wrapper for this class includes the location fields it appears that the Google API is not currently populating this object.  In the documentation for the [mediaItems](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems) resource the field location states *"Not yet available"*.

You can use the Google Drive API to get the location data though of a photo.

There is a [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80379228) raised to track this feature implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it looks like Google don't want to provide this.

You can star this bug in their tracker to upvote the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80379228 but it has not yet got any response from Google.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by using Google Drive sync. See my Android Application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levionsoftware.photo_map_for_google_photos

My App has been approved and works very well, but it's annoying that they don't open the door. In many cases it wouldn't work as I did. And at the end it's only a workaround...
EDIT: Some are having problems with that, because not all photos are synced to Google Drive...

Comment: Denny, your link is no longer working

Comment: @Ryan I found it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levionsoftware.instagram_map